# Unable to install Elasticsearch Reindexer 1.0.1 on JHipster 4.8.2

Tags: jhipster

This is my first project with JHipster.  I wanted to install Elasticsearch Reindexer module. I followed instructions provided in market place but while installing i get below error:

`C:\Project>yo jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer
C:\Project\node_modules\generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer\generators\app\index.js:27
  JhipsterGenerator = generator.Base.extend({});
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
    at Object. (C:\Project\node_modules\generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer\generators\app\index.js:27:37)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.get [as jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer:app] (C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\store.js:38:27)
    at Store.get (C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\store.js:61:39)`

I am able to install Entity Audit - this works fine.

Any suggestions/advice please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also encountered the same issue today and created an issue in the project page. 
https://github.com/geraldhumphries/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer/issues/34

not very familiar with node_modules and npm packages but to make it work, actually downgraded the version of yeoman-generator to a lower version 1.1.1 here's what i did:

** please note that this is just a quick fix i applied to be able to reindex my app :-) so check back in the project for an updated version.

1. go to where all packages are installed in npm, in windows should be at: 
   C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
2. Go to generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer\ and open package.json file
3. find "yeoman-generator"
   and change the version here of it to 1.1.1 like so: "yeoman-generator" : "1.1.1"
4. open a command line, go to C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer\ and execute the following command : 
   npm install
5. rerun the yo jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer command in your project directory

Good luck!

Comment: It seems that the issue has been fixed already. tested the new version in git and it's working with the latest yeoman-generator. we would need to wait for the release of this fix :-)